# I cannot deploy a basic html file in apache tomcat

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am making a small website as my first project. I have finalized to use Java Servlets and JSP for my Server-side scripting. I am learning it from O'Reilly's HeadFirst Servlets and JSP. I decided to use Apache-Tomcat as my web server and container. I downloaded it. I even have jdk 1.6 update 21. 
I unzipped apache in C:
It is running successfully as i get the default Tomcat home page when I type http://localhost:8080  in my browser.

In chapter 3 there is a small project called beer.
So I tried to make it.
I created a directory called beer under webapps `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.0\webapps\beer`. Inside it to just check the basics I created a html file called `form.html`. But when I try to access it via the browser `http://localhost:8080/beer/form.html` I get the following error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /beer/form.html
>
> type Status report
>
> message /beer/form.html
>
> description The requested resource
>   (/beer/form.html) is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.0

I have even tried using tomcat 6, but to no use.

---

Thank you for replying...
Actually my doubt is..that here i am trying to access a .html file which is not a servlet so does it even require a Deployment description????

well, there is only 1 servlet i planned to make (initially)....the one which is mentioned in the form (action= "....") in the html file i made....
so i thought of checking the basic html file before i deployed a servlet....btw...if i have to include the html file also in the DD, then what should i write in place of ServletName in the xml code u gave?
here are the contents of my web.xml (i modified it as u said...but dunno what to write in the Servlet Name)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>html page</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>form</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>html page</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/beer/form.html</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work just fine. Probably a typo in URL or filename. It's case sensitive as well. `/Beer` is not the same as `/beer`. Doublecheck the URL. Also, don't you have multiple instances of Tomcat running or extracted from the downloaded zip? You might have placed the new page in the wrong one and/or be running the wrong one. Try shutting down the Tomcat instance you think you're running and reload the homepage in the webbrowser. If the homepage doesn't disappear, then it's a different one.

Comment: I checked my url many times...
also i shut both the servers 6.0 and 7.0 and then strtd only 1...
still the problem persists...even the home page loads properly..
i am perplexed

Comment: C
i got the problem...
u were right....
i did a very shitty mistake in naming my file...
thanks a lot...
ur post made me check it again and again...and i got the problem

Answer (score 2):

The problem almost certainly is within your servlet declaration.

There is a file called **web.xml** within the **WEB-INF** folder of your webapp (`/webapps/beer/WEB-INF`). See if you can find it and post its content please.

This file declares how servlets will be mapped to request urls. Thus if there is a servlet mapped to the url extension `/*`:

```
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>ServletName</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

you will not be able to access files directly (i.e. `/beer/form.html` won't retrieve `form.html`) since the servlet `ServletName` will intercept any request on a url that starts with `http://localhost:8080/beer/`.

---

Btw, in case you wondered: the status code `HTTP 404` means that the file the url points to was not found.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error for more info on HTTP status codes.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is utterly wrong. A new folder doesn't require another servlet at all.

Comment: I didn't say that. Merely stating a possibility.

Comment: It's still wrong. For one thing, his "application" isn't using any servlets. For another, the `url-pattern` doesn't come into play until *after* the application name, whose mapping is not by default controlled by `web.xml`.

Comment: I was checking for that possibility in my answer. I don't understand your problem. I changed the `url-pattern`  to `/*` if that is what your fuss is about.

Comment: The OP is following a tutorial from O'Reilly. Who said it was empty?

Comment: Even then, this should not have produced a 404, but rather a different or blank page or a 5nn error. Unless the servlet is written on a smart way that it did `resposne.sendError(404);`, but I don't think the OP already got that far.

Comment: Honestly BalusC, I got that error a thousand times when I made the same mistake to request a file via a URL which was getting intercepted by a servlet. It produces a 404 status. That's why I posted this. I don't see your point.