# Tomcat Mapping Error

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I'm trying to follow the headfirst jsp and servlets book and I've encountered the following error.
HTTP Status 404 - /Beer/form.html

My folders are organised as following

tomcat -> webapps -> Beer -> form.html

Also inside the Beer folder I have another folder WEB-INF which contains the web.xml file.

First I thought maybe my tomcat is not working at all so I tested it using a previous servlet I've done. It worked.

I restarted the web server but I'm still getting this error.
I'm running Windows tomcat 7.0.47.

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Beer Expert Project</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Beer Expert Project<servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/beer.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The URL that I'm entering is

```
http://localhost:8080/Beer/form.html
```

I'm aware there is a similar question
[I cannot deploy a basic html file in apache tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317239/i-cannot-deploy-a-basic-html-file-in-apache-tomcat?rq=1)

But nothing from the answer accepted by that question works for me. Closing the web server does make the page dissapear. I checked that it's capital letters etc ...

Also the windows that pops up when starting tomcat doesn't have any warnings nor errors.

Comment: `tomcat doesn't have any warnings nor errors.` Can you see in the logs that whether Beer application is actually getting loaded or not ?

Comment: If that's all you have in your web.xml file, it's obviously not valid. It's not even well-formed.

Comment: @JBNizet unless there are things they did not show in the book then I'm not sure how this same web.xml file worked for them

Comment: It didn't. The book probably only shows the relevant parts of the web.xml file, and not the whole file. Here is an example of a complete web.xml file: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/web-xml.html. This is an old tutorial though and you should have 3.0/3_0 instead of 2.3/3_0. If you used a more recent book or tutorial, you would learn that you don't even need a web.xml file anymore to declare and map a servlet. That is done with annotations nowadays.

Comment: @JBNizet It could be that they are hiding code from me but I think it is that I've missed a slash before servlet-name.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have found the reason why this did not work.

I've missed a single slash before servlet-name.